# Terrible DotNetNuke performance

Tags: performance, iis, dotnetnuke

I'm involved with a project using **DotNetNuke version 05.01.04 Community Edition**. We are building our new Intranet using it, but performance is terrible.

We have five people adding pages and content to it and every 15-30 seconds **they experience a pause of 10 seconds** or longer before the system continues and the next screens loads.

The server is Windows 2003, 3.8GHz with 1GB of RAM. I'm told by our server admin that the CPU and memory performance don't appear to be the bottleneck.

We currently have 350 pages in the system, we a plan to add 1000. So we need to resolve this performance problem so that we can enter content and so we can go live.

I just can't see where the bottleneck is. Is there a good why to determine the bottleneck when using DotNetNuke?

**Modules installed**

- Publish:Engage *(Not currently in
  use)*
- Page Blaster *(Doesn't appear
  to providing caching when users
  logged in using Integrated
  Authentication)*
- SimpleGallery
- XMod
- Content Manager

**IIS Setup**
Application recycling completely disabled (Apart from a 2am recycle)

**New findings: 18th March 2010**
The main bottleneck was due to version 5.1.4 having a bug which caused 1300 database roundtrips on an average page, due to broken database in-memory caching. We've upgraded to 5.2.4 which has resolved this bottleneck.

Now the next biggest bottleneck is the navigation. We've used both [DDR:Menu](http://www.dnngarden.com/) and DDN:Nav, but both have a major impact on performance.

**Is there a navigation interface out there that doesn't drain performance so badly?**

Comment: Performance tweaked tried:
* Set-up DNN caching to 'Heavy'
* Installed Page Blaster
* Disabled IIS application recycling

Comment: What SQL Server version do you use? if express edition, then this is known to use only one CPU, maybe this is the bottleneck?

Comment: Do you have page compression (gzip or deflate) enabled?  Whitespace filtering enabled?  Also, try installing Firebug in Firefox with the YSlow add-on to see what resource could be taking the most time to load.

Comment: 1 GB is not nearly enough memory for this usage level.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - how do you know? We have customers on our dedicated servers with 1GB of RAM, running multiple ASP.NET sites including running DNN with 10,000's hits each hour. They don't have memory issues.

Comment: I know several ways, the most important of which is that you are below the vendor recommended minimum amount of memory for running an App + IIS + SS2005 all on the same box.  Granted, I am assuming that you are running SQL Server on the same box, so I'll apologize in advance if I am wrong.  However, I have seen a lot of these DNNv5/SS2005 configs at 1GB, and they frequently have this problem (not enough memory).

Comment: @Rbarry - didn't say that SQL is running on the same server so basing comments on that.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - also apologies if I sounded curt. Wasn't intended to be :). I kinda like to see all the facts before making an assessment. We also don't know what kind of disk storage they're using or more info about the rest of the hardware, e.g. is this a purpose built server running SCSI RAID 10k RPM disks or a 'bitsa' with a couple of SATA desktop drives? As you'll know, it makes all the difference.

Comment: We found one major performance bottleneck, which was due to a known issue in the version of DNN we were using which was blitzing the database with around 1,300 calls on every page viewed. Upgrading to the latest version resolved this particular issues. However we've still experiencing performance issues - but they may be related to the server we can running on.

Comment: The next two bottlenecks we've found are:

* The navigation menus performing lots of XML work slowing it down
* Url Rewriting also having the next biggest drain

Is there a navigation interface out there that is more efficient? It seems most navigation solutions are large performance drains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to start investigating this using performance profiling tools. For the DNN application itself I'd grab something like JetBrains [DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html) or Red Gate's [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/features.htm).

For the database SQL Server Profiler would be the first choice or a tool such as Red Gate's [SQL Response](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Response/index.htm).

Without profiling the application these you're going to be pulling at straws.

And as Tim pointed out in his comment, installing Firebug in Firefox with the YSlow add-in to see what resources are taking longest to serve to the browser.

Comment: You don't really need to pay for additional tools to do this.  Everything that is needed for basic performance analysis is already builtin.

Comment: @RbarryYoung - this is true, my main point was that he should be profiling the app/database instead of clutching at straws. Which tools he chooses is entirely down to him. Also true that there are free tools, but these are pro-tools I've used which do the job just a bit better (IMHO), that's all.

Comment: JetBrains DotTrace has been a life saver - it's shown us the initial database bottleneck (Along with SQL Profiler) then after fixing that it's shown us the navigation and Url Rewriting performance issues.

Comment: @peter - glad you narrowed it down.

Answer (score 4):

Mitchel Sellers has some good tutorials and checklists to go through with regards to performance in DNN.  Start with [Explaining High Performance DotNetNuke Configuration and Management](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/293.aspx) (which points to some of his earlier articles).

Comment: Thanks, will investigate these menu solutions as our current one is the current bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

I have several years of dnn development and maintainance experience, when I have this kind of problem, I start doing things from [database clean up](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/69/simple-dotnetnuke-performance-improvements.aspx). Next thing is, find for missing indexes, and/or rebuild all the indexes periodically (sql job scheduled for that) but major performance gain would be from clean up of table

Another good considerations would be, disabling trace, debug mode to false and turn off features of dnn that you don't use (scheduler is the first one to turn off)

Edit: consider [keep alive](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/1203/Windows-Hosting-Performance-Scalability.aspx) as well
Hope this helps

Comment: We've now added additional indexes and disabled scheduler. Although none of these things were the main bottleneck and haven't improved performance noticably.

Answer (score 0):

Is your database on that server?  If so, just throw in some more RAM, or get a faster disk array...

Comment: The database is on a seperate server. RAM on both web and database servers are at the maximum allowed by the motherboard/OS.

Comment: You can't convince me that your server only allows 1 GB of RAM. If that's true, I'm impressed that you managed to install Windows 2003 on a smartphone!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating this lot of pages directly through TSQL? It's not hard to do and may save you a lot of time.

Comment: We are now past the adding pages level and into the trying to achieve a decent enough level of performance to launch stage(!)