# IIS6 performance tuning for DotNetNuke

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, dotnetnuke

I've been tasked with looking into performance tuning my company's intranet server. It runs DotNetNuke which suffers from poor performance. It also runs a number of other web apps (mix of asp and asp.net).

Could anybody give me a brief list of common performance tweaks that can be made to IIS6?

Comment: Not voting to close as a dupe, but there is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199866/terrible-dotnetnuke-performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not profile the application and the database as I suggested in the answer I provided to the related question here:

> [Terrible DotNetNuke performance - Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199866/terrible-dotnetnuke-performance/2200147#2200147)

Otherwise you won't know what to tune, you really need to get a full picture of how the app is performing and where the bottlenecks are. You can only get these metrics by profiling, perf counters and tangible data.