# IIS Slow response on POST requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, iis, post, performance

I have a web app that is calling a web handler .ashx via jquery POST on the production server it works fine but on the testing and locally all POST requests are much slower. All GET requests are very fast but POST are much too slow. What could be causing that? How can I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons, but the first thing you need to do is profile the application to find out where the bottleneck exists. The [answer I provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199866/terrible-dotnetnuke-performance/2200147#2200147) suggested some profiling tools.

It could well be that your production, test and local environments are configured sufficiently differently enough (hardware, OS, database configs) to cause this issue.